# How to make seconds work for an input type time

Tags: javascript, html, zend-framework

this is my first time asking something here so i hope i'll it right

I'm currently trying to record times (like the time a runner took to run a marathon) and am using a time input, for seconds to appear i had to put the attribute step="1", the problem is that my form returns me an error (am using zend 3) on chrome if the input returns a value that ends by 00 seconds but only when using chrome, it works perfectly when using Firefox.

Has someone already foud a workaround to make chrome act like firefox ?
3

Or maybe is there another way to register times ?

(Sorry if my English is bad, not my native language)

Comment: can you please post your form element code and the html code of the form element?

Comment: As @KoKsPfLaNzE said, having the form error message (and its configuration) would be helpful.
Could you also post the HTTP-POST request content of both browsers?